# How to customize the default authentication system in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to customize the authentication system that comes with Django.

I would like to display more columns like the relationships with other models.

I know how to alter how the models registered using admin.py appear on the admin site, however, I am not sure how to change the default authentication system.

How can I change which authentication is the default in Django?

Comment: Refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to [store additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) (from the Django docs).

Django has built-in support for this kind of data; you create a new model with a `OneToOneField` to `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and the framework adds some convenience methods to traverse that relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The docs have an entire section on customizing an authentication backend:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#authentication-backends

Just subclass your own and add it into the auth backends in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what i was looking for was the list_display but this list_display were custom made... so more info read up in [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods) . Many examples are given.